# How to deal with dynamic ids in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fill in a grid using Selenium Webdriver. The Xpath contains dynamic ids. I have managed to locate one cell using

```
"starts-with" driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[starts-with(@id,'Value')]")).SendKeys("1"); for this XPath `//*[@id="Value_36761_2"]`,
```

but the problem is that I have to fill in other cells which have the same

```
 attribute ( //*[@id="Value_36761_9"] , //*[@id="Value_36761_5"],
    //*[@id="Value_36761_18"]  )
```

. The number "`36761`" is always changing.

Could you give me a hint, please?

Comment: Since its dynamic id, the better approach is to create xpath based on static values, ex: classname, tags etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'Value_[0-9]{5}') and ends-with(@id,'_\d')]
```

Note : Assuming that number coming after "Value" is 5 digit.

Comment: Hello!  I have tried //*[starts-with(@id,'Value_[0-9]{5}') and ends-with(@id,'_9')] and also another option //*[starts-with(@id,'Value') and ends-with(@id,'_9')] and for both I have the same error ".... is not a valid XPath expression."

Comment: Which browser and version you are testing against

Comment: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: expression "ends-with" is supported in xpath 2.0 and chrome browser still use xpath 1.0 and its expression. Above xpath might work with other browsers. Try it once with other browser.

Comment: For your case, check if xpath with only //*[starts-with(@id,'Value_[0-9]{5}')] works as its supported in xpath 1.0 in chrome. This will return you list of webelements so you may have to use "findElements" method. Then work way your watyaround to each element in for loop. Let me know if this works